# Print.css differences between IE and Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, printing, cross-browser

I have created a print.css style sheet for printing and am not getting consistent results in terms of print between the different browsers.

For example, in IE, my print is a lot smaller and is hardly readable. In Firefox and Chrome, it prints out fine and is more legible.

In terms of font size, I have tried increasing and decreasing the font size using ems and pts, but the results are the same where IE prints out alot smaller and ff and chrome print out in a bigger size.  I am using the fonts: Verdana,"Arial Narrow",  helvetica, sans-serif;

Any recommendations for fixing this problem?  Anyone else having this problem? Unfortunately, printing in PDF is not an option.

Thanks

Comment: Are you just going to File->Print in the browser to print a webpage?

Comment: @Andrew
Hi no, the user would click a print link on the page and it would fire  javascript: window.print();

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack and used this IE hack for my print.css. The solution is to put a \9 at the end:

```
 font-size: 6pt;            /* font size for FF, Chrome, Safari */
 font-size: 12pt\9;         /* font size for IE8, IE9, and IE10
```

This seems to have worked for me.